# How to get the result from IObservable subscription without a blocking call?

Tags: c#, observable, system.reactive, idisposable, minio

I'm trying to get filenames within a bucket of my MinIO server using the [`ListObjectsAsync`](https://docs.min.io/docs/dotnet-client-api-reference.html#listObjects) method.

Here is the relevant code:

```cs
public async Task<string> GetFileName(string userID, string datasetID) 
{
    ListObjectsArgs args = new ListObjectsArgs()
        .WithBucket(userID)
        .WithPrefix(datasetID)
        .WithRecursive(true);

    var files = _minio.ListObjectsAsync(args);

    List<string> fileNames = new();
    
    IDisposable subscription = files
        .Subscribe(item => 
            fileNames.Add(item.Key),
            () => Console.WriteLine(fileNames.Count)
        );
      
    // I want to return one of the filenames here!
    return ""; 
}
```

The code above fills the list `fileNames` as expected and prints out the correct number of files within the respective locations. However, I would like to user the data within the function above.
I know I could do the following:

```cs
files.ToList().Wait();
```

However, this is a blocking call. Should I simply wrap this call into `Task` or is there some other (better) way to get the required data?

Comment: How about you await `_minio.ListObjectsAsync(args);` Then loop through the files? Do you only want to await the task list one at a time?

Comment: @Luminous this will give me only the first item, will it not? See my comment in the accepted answer, which is similar.

Comment: I familiarized myself with what `ListObjectsAsync()` returns. That method returns a Subscription. Calling `Subscribe()` returns an IDisposable. Call subscription.Dispose() when you find the file you want. Then to emit your file you would want to emit an event and listen to it in your dependent class. I haven't used minio before, but I would use events instead of using the async/await pattern. Someone probably knows the answer using async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing the subscribe, return `files.ToTask()`.

EDIT

As you mention in the comments, first use `.ToList()` in order to gather all the next events into one event. If you are looking for a specific file, like another answer implies, then use `.Filter`.

Also I think your return type should be a Task with an array of strings rather than a single string... (Unless you only want one file and have filtered out all the others.)

Comment: tested with `files.ToList().ToTask()` which seems to work. Without `ToList()` first, I only get the first item...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check the files you received one by one and stop processing the rest of them when the current file meets a specific condition. Like:

```
CancellationTokenSource source = new CancellationTokenSource();
CancellationToken token = source.Token;
Item file = null;
files.Subscribe(
        item => {
            if (item.Key=="MyFile")
            {
                file=item; 
                source.Cancel();
            }
        },
        () => Console.WriteLine(fileNames.Count),
        token );
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all.